# Setting read-only of PDF files

Tags: powershell, pdf

Currently my read-only function does not set read-only of PDF files.

```
function SetFolderItemsReadOnly{
    Param([string]$Path)
    $files = Get-ChildItem $Path -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    foreach($file in $files) {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $file.FullName -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true

    }
}
```

How do I do it for pdf files?

Comment: Can't reproduce. The file is possibly open elsewhere. Or you confuse PDF internal modification protection with a file system read-only attribute.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @wOxxOm When I use my function on a folder containing some files, both .txt and .pdf only the .txts files are being set to read-only. That was not the case for you?

Comment: It works for me, of course. There's nothing special about pdf files whatsoever. BTW 3rd reason why it doesn't work for you: security permissions of the files.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh, you're right. The issues happens when there's something like [ or ] in the filename...

Comment: Use LiteralPath instead of Path in your call.

Comment: @BenjaminS.Sorterup try with `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`

Comment: I have. Do I need some specific version of Powershell? Powershell doesn't suggest -LiteralPath when I write -L but it does not fail the compilation. But I'm still not able to set it to read-only.

Comment: Use `-literalpath` in both `get-childitem` and `set-itemproperty`

Comment: @wOxxOm That did it! Thank you!

Comment: Now please add an answer, someone... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -literalpath in both get-childitem and set-itemproperty

credits: @wOxxOm